# The Picker isnt getting the data from the array which is being pulled from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uipickerview

I have 2 pickers here and the values of the pictures are assigned to the data that is being pulled from firebase. It is assigned to an array and then those values are assigned to the picker. This isn't working and I'm not really sure why. 
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class SearchSelectVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var locationPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLB: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLB: UILabel!

    var locData: [String] = [String]()
    var dateData : [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initPickers()
        getLoc(onCompletion: { (data) in
            print(data)
            self.locData = (data)
            print(self.locData)
       })
    }


    func getDate(onCompletion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
        var data : [String] = []
        let selectedLoc = locationLB.text
        var dateRef: DatabaseReference!
        dateRef = Database.database().reference().child("launch").child((selectedLoc)!)
        dateRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                data.append(key)
                print("date = \(key)")
                //print(data)

            }
            onCompletion(data)
        }
    }
    func getLoc(onCompletion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void){
        print("here3")
        var data : [String] = []
        var locRef: DatabaseReference!
        locRef = Database.database().reference()
        print("here4")
        locRef.child("launch").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                data.append(key)
                print("location = \(key)")
                //print(data)


            }
            onCompletion(data)
        }

    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if(pickerView == locationPicker){
            return 1
        }
        else if(pickerView == datePicker){
            return 1
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView == locationPicker) {

            return locData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView == datePicker) {

            return dateData.count
        }
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView == locationPicker) {
            return locData[row]
        }
        else if(pickerView == datePicker){
            return dateData[row]
        }
        return "thisisbad"
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if(pickerView == locationPicker){
            updateLabelLoc()
            getDate(onCompletion: { (data) in
                print(data)
                self.dateData = data
            })
        }
        else if(pickerView == datePicker){
            updateLabelDate()
        }
    }
    func updateLabelLoc(){
        let location = locData[locationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        locationLB.text = location
    }
    func updateLabelDate(){
        let date = dateData[datePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        dateLB.text = date
    }
    func initPickers(){
        locationPicker.delegate = self
        locationPicker.dataSource = self
        datePicker.delegate = self
        datePicker.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

The data is in a completion handler and on completion, it returns the data from the database correctly. The pickers display without any data inside of them.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create:

```
func updatePickers() {
   locationPicker.reloadAllComponents()
   datePicker.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

After the `print(self.locData)` (in `getLoc(onCompletion:)` (in viewDidLoad()), put:

```
self.updatePickers()
```

Comment: Let me know if it works.  Your completion handler is most likely finishing after loading all the elements on the screen.  So you need to update the mainUI after your data has finish loading.  This should do the trick.  You may need to add that to your other closures in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by other closures, sorry I'm new to swift, and programming in general.

Comment: it looks like in your didSelectRow you have another:
  getDate(onCompletion: { (data) in
                print(data)
                self.dateData = data
            })

You may need to add it there as well.